# How can I create these images/col?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new, and I want to learn how can I create these images to be in the center of the page and I want to be a very small gap between them? May you please help me? I was searching on the internet about how can I create this, but unfortunately I wasn't very lucky. What's the code for this container, row, or column?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNAJU.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? You wrap the two images inside a `div` container and apply flex property to it. Then use a padding of 5px on each image to get that little space between. Also I have used a custom height to the container, you can adjust it according to your need.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container > div {
    padding: 0px 5px;
    max-width: 90%;
    height: 325px;
}
  
.container div img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
    .container {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .container > div {
        padding: 10px 5px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1/5616/3744.jpg?hmac=kKHwwU8s46oNettHKwJ24qOlIAsWN9d2TtsXDoCWWsQ"/></div>
        <div><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667.jpg?hmac=J04WWC_ebchx3WwzbM-Z4_KC_LeLBWr5LZMaAkWkF68"/></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but it's really close, the width needs to be 745 and the height is 325px and it's not in the center, and I don't want to cover the whole screen I want to be the width of the container 80% maybe or 70%. Like in the image I posted. Also when I go to mobile view, the images are not responsive for mobile view :/

Comment: I have updated the answer. Added 325px to the image container, as for the width I am not sure if 745 mean the width of the container or of the image itself. I have vertically centered the images and you have responsive image on mobile devices as well. You can check it out once.

Comment: From the bottom of my heart, thank you.

Comment: Hello again, you solved the answer to my question several days ago, is it too much for you to look at this question it's kind of related to this container? Thank you for your time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72984040/container-exceeding-width-100

Comment: Looks like it got solved. Let me know if you still has issues.