# Container exceeding width 100%

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, width

I was wondering can anyone of you help me with this container width problem. When I'm in mobile view, container width is exceeding 100% for some reason. I tried reducing the width to 90% and it does solve the problem from a mobile view but then at the PC it moves images to left instead of staying in the middle. I tried also adding overflow: hidden/auto but it cuts my image in the half and it doesn't let me scroll.

Here is the mobile view, pay attention to the white space at the left.

[image]

This is the image on the PC and I want this to stay exactly as it is. Changing the width of the container is moving these images to the left.

[image]

```css
 .container1 {
            
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        
        .container1 > div {
            padding: 0px 5px;
            max-width: 100%;
            height: 325px;
        }
          
        .container1 div img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
            
        }
        
        @media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
            .container1 {
                flex-direction: column;
            }
        
            .container1 > div {
                padding: 10px 5px;
            }
        }
    
    .zgrade {
      position: relative;
      max-width: 80%;
     
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      overflow: hidden; 
      width: 745px;
      min-width: 466px;
    }
    
    .zgradeimg {
      width: 500px;  
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .zgrade:hover img {
      -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container1">
     <div class="row justify-content-center w-80">
     <div class="zgrade">
      <a href="zgradaA.html"><img src="assets/img/szgrade/zgradaA.jpg"/></a>
      </div>
            
            <br>
            
            
       <div class="zgrade"><img src="assets/img/szgrade/zgradaB.jpg"/></div>
        </div>
         </div>
    
                        <div class="p-6"></div>
                       
        <div class="container1">
          <div class="row justify-content-center w-80">
            <div class="zgrade"> <img src="assets/img/szgrade/zgradaC.jpg"/></div>
            
            <br>
            
            
        <div class="zgrade"><img src="assets/img/szgrade/zgradaD.jpg"/></div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i tried to changed all your width to max-width so they are not overflowing, move your media queries at the bottom. See below sample I made and let me know if this fixes your problem.

```css
.container1 {
            
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        
        .container1 > div {
            padding: 0px 5px;
            max-width: 100%;
            height: 325px;
        }
          
        .container1 div img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
            
        }
        

    
    .zgrade {
      position: relative;
      max-width: 100%;     
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      overflow: hidden; 
      max-width: 745px;
      min-width: 320px;
    }
    
    .zgradeimg {
      width: 500px;  
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .zgrade:hover img {
      -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    
            @media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
            .container1 {
                flex-direction: column;
            }
        
            .container1 > div {
                padding: 10px 5px;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="container1">
     <div class="row justify-content-center w-80">
     <div class="zgrade">
      <a href="zgradaA.html"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7c/Angel_of_the_North_silhouette.jpg/1024px-Angel_of_the_North_silhouette.jpg"/></a>
      </div>
            
            <br>
            
            
       <div class="zgrade"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7c/Angel_of_the_North_silhouette.jpg/1024px-Angel_of_the_North_silhouette.jpg"/></div>
        </div>
         </div>
    
                        <div class="p-6"></div>
                       
        <div class="container1">
          <div class="row justify-content-center w-80">
            <div class="zgrade"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7c/Angel_of_the_North_silhouette.jpg/1024px-Angel_of_the_North_silhouette.jpg"/></div>
            
            <br>
            
            
        <div class="zgrade"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7c/Angel_of_the_North_silhouette.jpg/1024px-Angel_of_the_North_silhouette.jpg"/></div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Yes it does, from the bottom of my heart thank you, I just increased, I just made a small change, in mobile view the images were too small so I Increased the width in .zgrade.

Comment: Hey I would like to ask you 1 more question if possible, when I change resolution to 1600 and 1366 my images are messed up, here is the picture. https://ibb.co/HhxKVG0      Do you know how to make these images responsive for all resolutions ? Should I make image size smaller ?

Comment: putting a max-width will help you on responsiveness a lot. on images if you want it to not mess up and retain their resolution put object-fit: contain but if it is inside a container object-fit: cover. If I understand your question right.

Comment: Hey Crystal, may you please check this post if you have the time of course. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73097613/container-is-exceeding-on-samsung-mobile-view

Comment: @thenr page doesnt exists.